# Java while loop mysterious iteration

Tags: java, while-loop

Can somebody teach me how the while loop in find method is working? Does that somehow iterates the parent array from 0 to the endpoint automatically? until paren[i] != i?

```
static int find(int i) 
{ 
    while (parent[i] != i) 
        i = parent[i]; 
    return i; 
} 
  
// Finds MST using Kruskal's algorithm 
static void kruskalMST(int cost[][]) 
{ 
    int mincost = 0; // Cost of min MST. 
  
    // Initialize sets of disjoint sets. 
    for (int i = 0; i < V; i++) 
        parent[i] = i; 
  
    // Include minimum weight edges one by one 
    int edge_count = 0; 
    while (edge_count < V - 1) 
    { 
        int min = INF, a = -1, b = -1; 
        for (int i = 0; i < V; i++) 
        { 
            for (int j = 0; j < V; j++)  
            { 
                if (find(i) != find(j) && cost[i][j] != 0 && cost[i][j] < min)  
                { 
                    min = cost[i][j]; 
                    a = i; 
                    b = j; 
                } 
            } 
        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's difficult to see what you're not grasping - it executes as written.

`find` is called with some value of `i`

Does the i'th entry in the `parent` array contain the value `i`?  Yes, then control proceeds to the return statement and we're done.

Otherwise, set the value in `i` to the value from the i'th entry of the 'parent' array.

Does the i'th entry in the `parent` array contain the value `i`?
Yes, then control proceeds to the return statement and we're done.

Otherwise, set the value in `i` to the value from the i'th entry of the 'parent' array.

… and keep doing this ...

The overall logic seems to be that each entry in the `parent` array is supposed to identify its parent entry, except that the topmost entry has itself for its parent.

However, since all entries in `parent` are initialized such that the i'th entry contains `i`, and nothing changes that, it seems the code shown is incomplete.